# Projectile trajectory / flight path

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Red is the desired path]

I'm trying to make a projectile which has movement behaviour shown as red in the diagram.
What I know and have now is two vectors; Start and End.
The end goal is to have some randomness of the arc at iteration and projectile velocity change in a lerp-fashion. I've done linear movement generations before, but nothing like this.

If my question feels like asking you to do my work for me (My usual fear of asking questions as a novice coder) could I have some tips and hints on what methods/commands I should look into? The language is C# and Unity version is 5.6

EDIT # 1

After getting some head-direction I could achieve something closer to the end-goal function of this.

[image]

> Blue linear line is just representation of distance and angle between A(initiation point) and B(target). The red arc is the trajectory I'm willing to make my projectile to move as.

Fortunately, I figured what I wanted my path to guide the projectile to follow was a cubic bezier and got the result in editor shown in the diagram above with A, B, modA, and modB. There are just a few more things I need to get working on actually mounting the projectile to follow this path and control its velocity and etc. Following are more questions which I couldn't get through today.

First, the general condition is A is fixed and B is not. In order to maintain the generally desired flight path, I figured I need another virtual line lineB(from modA to modB) to sync lineA's angle and distance so when B(the target) is moving around in all directions the arc is not too extremely skewed, but in my attempts today either I got the wrong angle from lineA or something modA just orbited around A and the numbers were weird like angle changing in straight line movement of B from A.

Second is to have some random-but-similar variety of the red arc after the first projectile fires and to the next. I'm guessing this would be somewhat easier when I get past the first one since it's just matter of controlling lineB.

Edit # 2

All the functions asked above are resolved: A path is generated from A to B with arc made with modA and modB as well as the randomness of modA and modB at each iteration as well as modA and modB adjusting according to B's position in real time.

Now All that's left is to actually make the projectile follow the path and control its velocity till reaching B. Below is the code generating the arc-path. How should I approach this?

```
public Transform[] controlPoints = new Transform[4];
public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

private int curveCount = 0;
private int SEGMENT_COUNT = 50;

private void DrawCurve()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < curveCount; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= SEGMENT_COUNT; i++)
        {
            float t = i / (float)SEGMENT_COUNT;
            int nodeIndex = j * 3;
            Vector3 pixel = CalculateCubicBezierPoint(
                t,
                controlPoints[nodeIndex].position,
                controlPoints[nodeIndex + 1].position,
                controlPoints[nodeIndex + 2].position,
                controlPoints[nodeIndex + 3].position);

            lineRenderer.positionCount = (((j * SEGMENT_COUNT) + i));
            lineRenderer.SetPosition((j * SEGMENT_COUNT) + (i - 1), pixel);
        }
    }
}

private Vector3 CalculateCubicBezierPoint(float t, Vector3 start, Vector3 modA, Vector3 modB, Vector3 end)
{
    float u = 1 - t;
    float t2 = Mathf.Pow(t, 2);
    float u2 = Mathf.Pow(u, 2);
    float t3 = Mathf.Pow(t, 3);
    float u3 = Mathf.Pow(u, 3);

    Vector3 p = u3 * start;
    p += 3 * u2 * t * modA;
    p += 3 * u * t2 * modB;
    p += t3 * end;

    return p;
}
```

---

Comment: It looks like you don't want it to be physics based. Just random? Anyways it would be good to add what you have tried. Hint: Generate random path and put them in list then iterate over them

Comment: That's correct. I took this as a vector math kind of problem. The red arc is the sample type of movement behavior I'd like to make and iterations to be in similar fashion .

Comment: @Programmer So, I should first generate a path separately, then make the object follow it, right? I'll start looking into that now! thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you in my first comment. You have to modify your question with what you've tried from my first comment and if there is a problem.

Comment: @Programmer Can you please check out my edit? I've got some things done and got more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AnimationCurve.

you can edit the "graphic curve" in the inspector (public variable AnimationCurve) then use this srcipt to move object along the path.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AnimationPath : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public AnimationCurve XCurve;

    public float TotalTravelTime = 5.0f;

    public float TravelSpeed = 50.0f;

    public float XRange = 10.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        StartCoroutine("Travel");
    }

    IEnumerator Travel()
    {
        float ElapsedTime = 0.0f;

        while(ElapsedTime < TotalTravelTime)
        {
            float XPos = XCurve.Evaluate(ElapsedTime/TotalTravelTime) * XRange;

            transform.position = new Vector3(XPos, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + TravelSpeed * -Time.deltaTime);

            yield return null;

            ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such kindness! I'll try this out once I finish current trial tipped by Programmer. I figured what I need is a cubic bezier path and just got done with drawing that path with LineRenderer. Your tip scared me heck lot when I first glanced it at first because I was previously going totally more complicated way of doing this: Get point A(start) and B(End) with point modA and modB to adjust the curvature dynamically at iteration where A is fixed at instantiation, B is reactively adjusted by realtime position change, and modA and modB accordingly with angle and distance of A and B.

Comment: with my solution, you can edit curve inside a graph manually. It's easy. The scripts works perfect.

Comment: By reading it I doubt not. But I'm curious about variation, though. The end goal of this function is to have; say there are 3 consecutive projectiles firing in this path-manner and they have some slight difference of path-shapes to make things look more interesting.

Comment: I've tried out your script tweaking bits around and adding some stuff and I couldn't quite get a liking-result. Still, great thanks for the tip, though. This got me learn more about AnimationCurve usage! I've also edited my question, could you take a look and give some more hints if you don't mind?